# DCHP changes not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

Made a change to the win2k8 server we have running as a domain controller. I changed the subnet mask from 255.255.252.0 to 255.255.255.0 and the change does not seem to be changing on the client systems. I did all the regular stuff, ipconfig /release /renew , reboot, disable the nic, and nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify where you changed the subnet mask. Was it on the server's LAN interface, the DHCP scope, or both?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that DHCP had a setting in the scope to have this 252.0 in there that is why when I set the 255.0 as the subnet it was still giving out 252.0. 
I made the change and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the DHCP service on the server so the new configuration would be used.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the server itself into the same subnet? Machines on the same LAN segment as the server will only get addresses with subnets that match the server's. A DHCP server can give out addresses in several subnets, but requests for subnets that are different from those on your interfaces need to be forwarded from switches or routers on those networks.